# How to set one region over the other (and not beside it) in Omega theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I´m using Omega theme in a Drupal 7 installation, and don´t know how to put the sidebar second right below the sidebar first.

Under Zone and region configuration I have the content section, with the content zone inside it.
Content zone has 12 columns.
Inside it I have 2 regions:
content (6 cols).
sidebar second (3 cols).

If I add there another region, (sidebar first in my case) Omega puts it along the other two, and I can only set the weight of each one to determine wich one will appear first.
**But what if I want one region under the other?**

I´m using delta module to create different layouts according to some variables, but every time I try to set one region over the other it fails. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

[image: Here´s what I want]

UPDATE: How may I use context to do that in case it is possible?
[image: My context condition choices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging and reading what **Mohammed** says (thanks!), commenting my question above, I´ve found that there´s in fact a solution: You should allow context to manage that specific twist you want to do for that special viewport.

The problem is that context won´t allow that, there´s no viewport context.
But there´s a new module out there called [Context Breakpoint](http://drupal.org/project/context_breakpoint) that would do the trick.

It´s important to remember what the readme file says though:

> Adaping to resolution should mostly be done with CSS and media
>   queries, but sometimes you just can not do everything you need to do
>   in CSS. This module detects screen and browser size with Javascript
>   and sets a cookie accordingly. This means that Javascript and cookies
>   must be enabled. Also, after changing the browser size, a reload will
>   obviously be required for the changes to show up.

Answer (score 1):

The side bars are used to create columns and not for placing it one on top of the other.

If you want a single column then you would go for one of the three. If you want two columns go with any two of them and if you want three columns go for all three.

As for placing contents one on top of the other the blocks should be used for that. Let us say you have two blocks one to show the latest articles and another to place the login box and you want the articles to be on top of the login box then you would go with one of the side bars and content and place both the blocks in the same sidebar and arrange it as you would want it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mohammed. But what if "some" blocks that I have in sidebar first, need to be inside "content" for a specific viewport? I thought that it would be easy if there were two regions in the sidebar, so I would move just one of them... how may I do that?

Comment: you could control that with the context module. depending on the context you can change the block to different regions

Comment: Thanks again for your kind reply Mohammed. I´ve tried that, but I don´t have any context to select related to the viewport (I´ve updated the post so I can show you what are my conditions). I´ve tried the "context" condition, but don´t know what should I do there. Maybe just type some mediaqueries? Thanks again!

Comment: you need to select on want condition you want the blocks to change. then use that to trigger an action. in the action you can decide what contents would be shown in which region...

Comment: on what conditions do the blocks change. does it depend on the path? content type? or some thing else?

Comment: Just the viewport, if I access using a tablet, they take the "narrow.css".

Comment: ok so you are looking for a responsive theme then I guess Adaptive theme is a better choice http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme It has got lots of settings to define depending on the device and view port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I´ve found a workaround based on what you said (that context should do the trick). There´s this module (Context Breakpoint) that does just that. Haven´t tested it yet though :) Going to do just that. I´ve posted it below just in case anyone else wonders... THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn't really with Omega, it's more in the way that divs work.

You can't float divs sequentially that way without putting one inside the other.

What you want to do requires putting one region *inside* another, not on top of.

You could make custom template files and a custom grid that puts one zone alongside the other, but you'd lose the ability to extend each zone to 100% width, limiting your design options.

One javascript solution is good old Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ which essentially gives you the equivalent of a  "float: top-left;" css rule.